# OS X Files starting with ._

Tags: macos, file

Can someone please explain, why **OS X** creates `._` files?
When i copy files into another folder, everything works fine as usual, but in addition also files starting with `._` are created. For example:
I copy movie.mp4 into another empty folder, i get two files after copying finished:

```
._movie.mp4 (size approx.: 4kb)
movie.mp4 (same size as the original movie.mp4)
```

Is there a way to prevent **OS X** from doing so?
Because i am working with some hidden files, it is important to see them. But theses `._` files are disturbing.

Comment: For the sake of interest, why was this question downvoted (-3)...looks OK...any special reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `._[filename]` files are the extended attributes of the given file. They are usually created when copying from an HFS format disk to a non-HFS disk (like FAT)

You can recursively merge them back into the files (and delete them) using the [dot_clean](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dot_clean.1.html) utility on OS 10.5+

Suppose we have these 4 `.PDF` files on a HFS+ volume (and the `.DS_Store` file):

```
$ ls -la
total 18672
drwxr-xr-x@  7 andrew  staff      238 Sep 17 17:00 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 10 andrew  staff      340 Sep 17 16:51 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 andrew  staff     6148 Sep 17 17:00 .DS_Store
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 andrew  staff  2321922 Mar  1  2010 P01.PDF
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 andrew  staff  2200305 Mar  1  2010 P02.PDF
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 andrew  staff  2416249 Mar  1  2010 P03.PDF
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 andrew  staff  2608839 Mar  1  2010 P04.PDF
```

Now copy (with drag and drop) those same files to a FAT32 thumb drive and do a `ls` on that:

```
$ ls -la
total 18976
drwxrwxrwx@ 1 andrew  staff    16384 Sep 17 17:00 .
drwxrwxrwx@ 1 andrew  staff    16384 Sep 17 17:00 ..
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 andrew  staff     6148 Sep 17 17:00 .DS_Store
-rwxrwxrwx  1 andrew  staff     4096 Sep 17 17:00 ._.DS_Store
-rwxrwxrwx  1 andrew  staff     4096 Sep 17 17:00 ._P01.PDF
-rwxrwxrwx  1 andrew  staff     4096 Sep 17 17:00 ._P02.PDF
-rwxrwxrwx  1 andrew  staff     4096 Sep 17 17:00 ._P03.PDF
-rwxrwxrwx  1 andrew  staff     4096 Sep 17 17:00 ._P04.PDF
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 andrew  staff  2321922 Mar  1  2010 P01.PDF
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 andrew  staff  2200305 Mar  1  2010 P02.PDF
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 andrew  staff  2416249 Mar  1  2010 P03.PDF
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 andrew  staff  2608839 Mar  1  2010 P04.PDF
```

You can run `dot_clean` to merge the attributes back into the given files:

```
$ dot_clean .
$ ls -la
total 18816
drwxrwxrwx@ 1 andrew  staff    16384 Sep 17 17:04 .
drwxrwxrwx@ 1 andrew  staff    16384 Sep 17 17:00 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 andrew  staff     6148 Sep 17 17:00 .DS_Store
-rwxrwxrwx  1 andrew  staff  2321922 Mar  1  2010 P01.PDF
-rwxrwxrwx  1 andrew  staff  2200305 Mar  1  2010 P02.PDF
-rwxrwxrwx  1 andrew  staff  2416249 Mar  1  2010 P03.PDF
-rwxrwxrwx  1 andrew  staff  2608839 Mar  1  2010 P04.PDF
```

You need read / run access to the directories and the files to do this obviously.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

> 1. Open Terminal.
> 2. Execute this command:
>
> `defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores true`
>
> 3. Either restart the computer or log out and back in to the user account.`